# Which bits of Solr are not Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

The more I learn about Lucene, the more I realise that the features of Solr are just a wrapper around Lucene. At the moment, it feels like Solr is just Lucene with an HTTP API and web server.

So I'm curious, which bits of Solr are not just a wrapper around Lucene? The caches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene is the core search library while Solr is build over it however it extends Lucene and provides a lot of features over and above it.
Solr makes the easy of configuration (through schema & solr config), complex query and text analysis, scalable architecture design, replication, real time search, Clustering, cloud, integration with Nutch, Tika, UIMA, Carrot, DIH, Rest Full services, Ajax integration and much much much more.

Check for the [Detailed](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) list

```
A Real Data Schema, with Numeric Types, Dynamic Fields, Unique Keys
Powerful Extensions to the Lucene Query Language
Faceted Search and Filtering
Geospatial Search with support for multiple points per document and geo polygons
Advanced, Configurable Text Analysis
Highly Configurable and User Extensible Caching
Performance Optimizations
External Configuration via XML
An AJAX based administration interface
Monitorable Logging
Fast near real-time incremental indexing and index replication
Highly Scalable Distributed search with sharded index across multiple hosts
JSON, XML, CSV/delimited-text, and binary update formats
Easy ways to pull in data from databases and XML files from local disk and HTTP sources
Rich Document Parsing and Indexing (PDF, Word, HTML, etc) using Apache Tika
Apache UIMA integration for configurable metadata extraction
Multiple search indices
```